# Stop Windows 10 from sending ICMP Echo Replies

Tags: windows, ping, icmp

Is there a setting (in the registry perhaps) which disables Windows 10 from sending back ICMP Echo Replies? (Without just blocking them at the firewall)

Comment: A half-way humorous answer, with some serious reasoning: http://shouldiblockicmp.com

Comment: What would be the point? What's the reasoning behind this?

Comment: Honeypot for intrusion detection

Answer (score 0):

No, you have to block them either in the Windows Firewall or via another firewall.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no option to do that. Echo reply (one type of ICMP messages) is standard behaviour of network stack. ICMP messages have some sense why it is defined. Next to ping (echo request / echo reply) there are messages like unreachable, redirected etc.

In general you can block these messages in firewall but there is logical purpose why it is there...

You should know specifically why you want to do that. In case you want to "hide" the node it is not enough. The node will still answer e.g. ARP requests (and in case you will try to block even that / in theory possible / it will simply stop working ;-) ).

Answer (score 0):

Normally, no. Because ICMP is part of the basic functionality of IP protocol, in order to change it you will have to use an Open Source IP protocol and change the source code to meet your needs regarding this issue. So if you have the skills to use an alternate protocol instead of the Windows one something like that becomes possible. Try first looking at FreeRTOS and at [this](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v2.6.37/net/ipv4/tcp_ipv4.c).